# AJAX Request Failed in form send data using php ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need to send form data using `ajax`.

HTML:

```
<div class="" id="ajax-msg1"></div>
<form id="ajaxform" action="load.php">
   <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" id="my_token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>" />
   <button type="submit" name="submit" id="ajax-1">Send</button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ajax-1").click(function() {
        $("#ajax-msg1").html("<img src='loading.gif'/>");
        var formData = $("#ajaxform").serializeArray();
        var URL = $("#ajaxform").attr("action");
        $.ajax({
            url: URL,
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $("#ajax-msg1").html('<pre><code class="prettyprint">' + data + '</code></pre>');
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $("#ajax-msg1").html('<pre><code class="prettyprint">AJAX Request Failed<br/> textStatus=' + textStatus + ', errorThrown=' + errorThrown + '</code></pre>');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

But in action i see this error:

```
AJAX Request Failed
```

and not work form. how do fix this error?!

Comment: you should specify the data type that the response will send back

Comment: Try logging the formData.

Comment: @Pekka : dataType is optional.

Comment: At where you see the errors? You're using submit type for button, and never return false will lead normal behavior submit.

Comment: Am I wrong, or are you submitting a form with only a hidden field 'crsf_token', that originally comes from the server, only to POST it again to the server via Ajax?

Comment: @jeoj: i have another field for send data originally this is comment form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like "Norlihazmey Ghazali" said

change:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ajax-1").click(function() {
```

to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ajax-1").click(function( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();// avoid submitting the form here
```

Comment: Or he could easily use regular <input type="button"/> instead of submit one.